# php mail function sometimes works, sometimes fails and tells me to upgrade/update TLS. Solution?

Tags: php, email, ssl, xampp

Like the title says. Here is my function:

```
<?php
  //---------------EMAIL PORTION--------------------
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  set_error_handler("var_dump");

  $from_email = 'email2@website.com';
  $to = 'email@website.com';

  $subject = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
  
  $message = 
  '
  <html>
    <body>
      <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <h3>Hello Person, </h3>
        <img src="###########"/>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
  ';
  
  // Headers
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; // Defining the MIME version
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: \"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\" <".$from_email.">\r\n"; // Sender Email
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from_email . "\r\n";
    
  $sentMailResult = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

  if($sentMailResult) {
    echo "Email Sent Successfully: ", $sentMailResult;
  }
  else {
    die("Sorry but the email could not be sent, Please go back and try again!");
  }
```

Sometimes it works but most of the time it doesn't. I will be on the php page in my browser, and I will refresh it, and it will say email sent successfully. Then I'll refresh it and it will say failed. I am using Xampp for my server. When it fails I get the following in my server log:

```
sendmail: Error during delivery: TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls. [prod.outlook.com]
```

Then when it works, my mail log has this in it after the email info:

```
250 2.0.0 OK
QUIT
```

I have done everything I can think of and I am beyond confused. I have tried adding this line onto my httpd-ssl.conf file: `SSLProtocol all +TLSv1.2` But it doesn't seem to help. I don't understand why it can work sometimes but not all the time. My php.ini mail function should be set up correctly and it links to a sendmail folder and the ini in there should also be setup correctly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Apache version: 2.4.51

PHP version: 8.0.13

OpenSSL version: 1.1.1l

Comment: Try `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1` to disable the old versions

Comment: The SSLProtocol setting has no relevance here. This is about the connection which the (Apache) web server accepts. The problem you have is instead  about the connections originating from the PHP script. Looks like your PHP TLS stack does not support TLS 1.2, which is likely related to being a very very (very) old system. TLS 1.2 support was added to OpenSSL (which is the underlying stack used by PHP) in 2012. Please update your system, it likely has other problems too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm on a Windows 10 Pro PC and all Windows updates have been applied. The PC might be around 10 years old, but not sure if that has any effect. The Xampp installation is brand new and has Apache version 2.4.51 and PHP version 8.0.13. When you say "system" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @aynber I added that to the httpd-ssl.conf file and I still got the same error after restarting Apache: `Error during delivery: TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported`

Comment: @justdoingmyjob: In this case there is likely an old openssl version used by PHP. Check with `phpinfo()` which version is installed. It must be at least 1.0.1 to have TLS 1.2 support.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich OpenSSL version is 1.1.1l. Which as far as I understand supports TLS 1.2 and 1.3.

Comment: Would this have anything to do with the mail server itself? Also, is it possible to get more information from the mail() function return? I appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: *"OpenSSL version is 1.1.1l."* - that's strange. This should support TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3. I don't know what is happening then.

Comment: The weirdest part is that it does occasionally work. I have 5 emails in my inbox to prove it.  But 9/10 times it does not work. At least I can cross those off the list of potential problems now.

Comment: Found some relevant information:
MICROSOFT: We are fully aware that many customers will not have noticed the multiple Message Center posts and blog posts, and are not aware of clients or devices that are still using TLS1.0 to submit messages. With this in mind, starting in September 2021, we will reject a small percentage of connections that use TLS1.0 for SMTP AUTH. Clients should retry as with any other temporary errors that can occur during submission. Over time we will increase the percentage of rejected connections, causing delays in sending that more and more customers should notice.

Comment: Update: Have followed all the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#bkmk_protocol and restarted my computer, still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent so much time on this, and got help from people a lot smarter than me, and it never worked. PHPMailer is the way to go. Set it up and it worked the first try, and consistently works since. You don't even have to deal with any ini files.